# Change font in title page in beamer theme Lucy

Tags: beamer, fontspec, themes

I would like to change the font use for title page in  [Beamer theme Lucy](https://github.com/EagleoutIce/beamer-themes/blob/master/lucy/beamerthemelucy.sty). The style file uses a conditional

```
% load font
 \ifbtl@usefont@%
  \RequirePackage{aurical}%
  \RequirePackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces,ebgaramond]{newtxmath}%
  \RequirePackage[default]{lato}%
   \RequirePackage{mathastext}
  \AtBeginDocument{\fontseries{m}\selectfont}%
\def\lfseries{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}%
  \else%
\def\lfseries{\selectfont}%
   \fi%
```

and the title page is like

```
    \newcommand\btl@true{true}
\providecommand{\lucyUseAlternativeTitle}{false}
\ifx\lucyUseAlternativeTitle\btl@true
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{lucy}[1][] {
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge\color{cprimary}\inserttitle}
    \\[3.5em]
        \color{csecondary}\insertauthor
    \end{center}
}
\else
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{lucy}[1][] {
    \ifbtl@usefont@\Fontauri\fi%
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge\color{cprimary}\inserttitle}
    \\[3.5em]
        \color{csecondary}\insertauthor{} \(\circ\) \insertdate
    \end{center}
}
\fi
```

Instead of Fontauri I want to use EB Garmond ( or any other non calligraphic font) for the title. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `nofont`

[image: c]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme[nofont]{lucy} % use option nofont <<<<<<<<<<<

\title{Example Presentation}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```